# MarkLogic javascript how to get Namespace of an element node

Tags: javascript, namespaces, marklogic

I am writing a generic function that tries to get the Namespace of an element node returned from `cts.search` function.  The challenge I have is that you cannot get the namespace of an element. I tried using the `node.getAttributeNode("xmlns")` but this does not work either.  There seems to be no function in the documentation that supports xml namespaces in javascript

Here is the solution I am working with.

```js
'use strict';

const DB_ID = xs.unsignedLong("5944350410045404402") //Meters database
const INVOKE_OPTS = {"database": xdmp.database()}
const getRoots = (bdone,iterations,filters,output)=>{
  let filterQuery = filters.map((filter)=>{
     return cts.notQuery(cts.documentRootQuery(filter))
  })
  let rootDoc = xdmp.invokeFunction(()=>fn.subsequence(cts.search(cts.andQuery([])),1,1),INVOKE_OPTS)
  let isEmpty = rootDoc != null ? true:false
  if(isEmpty != true) {
    return output
  } else {
      //Advance path the document node
      let node =  rootDoc.toArray()[0].xpath("/node()").toArray()[0]
      let nodeKind = node.nodeKind
      let baseUri = node.baseUri
      let nodeName = xs.QName("foo")
      let nodeNs = ""
      switch(nodeKind) {
        case "element" : 
          nodeName = node.nodeName
          nodeNs = node.getAttributeNode("xmlns")
          break;
        case "object-node" : 
        case "array-node" :
          nodeName = "json"
          break
      } 
      let nodePath = xdmp.path(node)
      return {
         "kind" : nodeKind,
         "ns" : nodeNs,
         "name" : nodeName,
          "path" : nodePath
      }
        
  }
  
}
getRoots(false,0,[],[])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML nodes can use [`namespaceURI`](https://docs.marklogic.com/XMLNode.namespaceURI)

```
nodeNs = node.namespaceURI
```

You could also use XPath and the [`namespace-uri()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-namespace-uri) method:

```
nodeNs = node.xpath("namespace-uri(.)")
```